# How to grep or sed every word starting with w?

Tags: sed, grep

I have a file that has a story contained in it, and I need to practice using either grep or sed. I have tried `egrep -i '^w.' file.txt` and it gets most of the words, but I need every word starting with w ("Paperwork" is invalid, "working" is valid).

Answer (score 2):

Probably you'd need a regexp to isolate word start (`\b`) and recognize word characters, e.g. `\S`, see [documentation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html#ere) for more. So you could use the command

```
$ grep -oE '\bw\S*' inputfile
```

With `-o`, the result will be only the matching parts, with each match on a new line (even from the one input line), and `-E` to be able to use "extended regex" (the same as using `egrep`).

A more strict "word" match might use `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `\S`:

```
$ grep -oE '\bw[[:alpha:]]*' inputfile
```

That would result in "words" (character sequences) in the English character set, starting with "w".